# UIBezierpath Draw Loading Circle

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, uibezierpath, uianimation

I need to draw the loading graphic like the following image in iOS Using UIBezierPath. Can anyone suggest to me how to do this?

I need that loader graphic like a "svprogresshud"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this you will get some idea.

```
UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath addArcWithCenter:center radius:50 startAngle:0 endAngle:2 * M_PI clockwise:YES];
CAShapeLayer *progressLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

[progressLayer setPath:bezierPath.CGPath];
[progressLayer setStrokeColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.2].CGColor];
[progressLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
[progressLayer setLineWidth:0.3 * self.bounds.size.width];
[progressLayer setStrokeEnd:volume/100];
[_circleView.layer addSublayer:progressLayer];
```

Comment: change UI according to you .